# setValidity not working with ng-show

Tags: angularjs

my setValidity not working, the message ngshow not working well.

html:

```
<span ng-show="form.year_of_birth.$error.notAge &&
              form.year_of_birth.$touched">Your to Young</span>
```

js:

```
$scope.form.year_of_birth.$setValidity('notAge',false);
```

Comment: Please show the controller's code,  and the entire form. Or even better, create a fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

To create the various checks and to change the validity of the input form, you can use the [use-form-error](https://github.com/Stepan-Kasyanenko/use-form-error) directive.

In your case do this ([jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Stepan_Kasyanenko/7ov28ura/)):

```html
<form name="ExampleForm">
  <label>Enter number more then 7:</label>
  <input ng-model="dateBirth" name="dateBirth" use-form-error="notAge" use-error-expression="dateBirth&&dateBirth<7" />
  <div ng-show="ExampleForm.dateBirth.$error.notAge">Your to young</div>
</form>
```

Or you can use ngMessages:

```html
     <form name="ExampleForm">
  <label>Enter number more then 7 and less then 70:</label>
  <input ng-model="dateBirth" name="dateBirth" use-form-error="notAge" use-error-expression="dateBirth&&dateBirth<7" />
  <span use-form-error="isOld" use-error-expression="dateBirth&&dateBirth>70" use-error-input="ExampleForm.dateBirth"></span>
  <div ng-messages="ExampleForm.dateBirth.$error" class="errors">
    <div ng-message="notAge">Your a young</div>
    <div ng-message="isOld">Your a old</div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Neither snippet works correctly in chrome on Android. In particular, both ng-messages are showing

Comment: Sorry, snippets do not really work. You can see the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Stepan_Kasyanenko/rcd288an/), it definitely works!